# jQuery resize width on firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, resize, width

I'm doing some experiments with jquery n widths for a liquid column and I'm not sure why it isn't working on firefox.
It works fine on IE6,7,8 Chrome, Opera(sluggish).
I found some articles about firefox not recognizing the .resize attribute but no explanation/solution =\

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(midCol).width((window,$(window).width()) - 470)
 $(window).resize(function(){$(midCol).width((window,$(window).width()) - 470)
})
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Your problem is with your selector, simply change it to `$('#midCol')` to get the desired effect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#midCol').width($(window).width() - 470)
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('#midCol').width($(window).width() - 470)
    })
});
```

What version of Firefox are you using? I can't seem to reproduce `resize()` not working in Firefox (3.6.3). I suggest trying a simple demo page for the [resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) method and see if you're still having problems. If this example works, then your problem likely lies elsewhere and you'll need to include some more info.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(window).resize(function() {
                $('#log').append('<div>Handler for .resize() called.</div>');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="log"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: huh, I thought I had the last firefox. Mine is 3.5.9. I'll download the new one immediately. =\

I have a test page running on my dropbox.
 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3359906/cballenar.wordpress/hybridlayout.jquery/index.html

Comment: darn... i didn't see that.
Thanks!